# JPA Criteria API: Aggregating on Multiple Columns with IF Condition

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have following MySQL schema -

*Note: I understand that this is not an ideal schema but I am working with a legacy code so I don't have much of control over changing the schema completely*

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `subject` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `student_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `marks` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Sample Data -

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'Foo'),
    (2, 'Bar'),
    (3, 'Baz');

INSERT INTO `subject` (`id`, `student_id`, `title`, `marks`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'math', 25),
    (2, 1, 'physics', 35),
    (3, 1, 'chemistry', 45),
    (4, 2, 'math', 85),
    (5, 2, 'physics', 65),
    (6, 2, 'chemistry', 65);
```

Query which I am trying to write using **JPA Criteria API** -

```
SELECT st.name
     , max(if(sub.title = 'math', sub.marks, 0)) as math
     , max(if(sub.title = 'physics', sub.marks, 0)) as physics
     , max(if(sub.title = 'chemistry', sub.marks, 0)) as chemistry
FROM student st
LEFT OUTER JOIN subject sub ON st.id = sub.student_id
GROUP BY st.name;
```

Sample Result -

```
| name | math | physics | chemistry | 
| ---- | -----| --------| --------- | 
| Bar  | 85   | 65      | 65        | 
| Baz  | 0    | 0       | 0         | 
| Foo  | 25   | 35      | 45        |
```

What I have tried so far -

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<StudentMark> dataQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(StudentMark.class);

Root<Student> root = dataQuery.from(Student.class);
Join<Student, Subject> studentSubjectJoin = root.join(ReflectUtil.getFieldName(Student.class, Student::getSubjectMarks), JoinType.LEFT);

dataQuery.multiselect(root.get(ReflectUtil.getFieldName(Student.class, Student::getName)),
        criteriaBuilder.max(studentSubjectJoin.get(ReflectUtil.getFieldName(Subject.class, Subject::getValue))),
        criteriaBuilder.max(studentSubjectJoin.get(ReflectUtil.getFieldName(Subject.class, Subject::getValue))),
        criteriaBuilder.max(studentSubjectJoin.get(ReflectUtil.getFieldName(Subject.class, Subject::getValue))));

dataQuery.groupBy(root.get(ReflectUtil.getFieldName(Student.class, Student::getStudentId)));

this.entityManager.createQuery(dataQuery);
```

I am not able to figure out how to write **IF** inside **MAX** aggregate function as per SQL query.

Answer (score 5):

The query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT st.name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN sub.title = 'math' THEN sub.marks ELSE 0 END) as math
     , MAX(CASE WHEN sub.title = 'physics' THEN sub.marks ELSE 0 END) as physics
     , MAX(CASE WHEN sub.title = 'chemistry' THEN sub.marks ELSE 0 END) as chemistry
FROM student st
LEFT OUTER JOIN subject sub ON st.id = sub.student_id
GROUP BY st.name;
```

In Criteria API:

```
dataQuery.multiselect(root.get(Student_.name),
    criteriaBuilder.max(
        criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
            .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(studentSubjectJoin.get(Subject_.title), criteriaBuilder.literal("math")), studentSubjectJoin.get(Subject_.marks))
            .otherwise(criteriaBuilder.literal(0))
    ).alias("math"),
    criteriaBuilder.max(...)
    ...
);
```

(I used the static metamodel notation instead of the reflection calls for clarity; as a side note, you might want to consider doing the same, it improves readability a lot)

Answer (score 3):

Since IF is a MySQL proprietary clause, it's not easily accessible from JPA. But it can be built with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

```java
FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((Student st,
                                   Subject sub) -> {
    Integer math = alias(MAX(IF(sub.getTitle() == "math", sub.getMarks(), 0)),
                                                          StudentMarks::getMath);
    Integer physics = alias(MAX(IF(sub.getTitle() == "physics", sub.getMarks(), 0)),
                                                          StudentMarks::getPhysics);
    Integer chemistry = alias(MAX(IF(sub.getTitle() == "chemistry", sub.getMarks(), 0)),
                                                          StudentMarks::getChemistry);

    SELECT(st.getName(), math, physics, chemistry);
    FROM(st).LEFT_JOIN(sub).ON(sub.getStudent() == st);
    GROUP(BY(st.getName()));
});

return query.createQuery(em, StudentMarks.class).getResultList();
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.name,
       MAX(IF((t1.title = 'math'), t1.marks, 0)) AS math,
       MAX(IF((t1.title = 'physics'), t1.marks, 0)) AS physics,
       MAX(IF((t1.title = 'chemistry'), t1.marks, 0)) AS chemistry 
FROM STUDENTS t0  LEFT JOIN SUBJECTS t1  ON (t1.student_id = t0.id) 
GROUP BY  t0.name
```

(declared tuple):

```java
@Tuple
@Data //lombok
public static class StudentMarks {
    private String name;
    private int math;
    private int physics;
    private int chemistry;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select the data GROUPED only BY `Student.name` and `Subject.id` and then simply iterate over your DB results and create your DTOs. Thus you will get a more readable code that will not depend on your database (or database version).